# Angular is automatically resending failed http requests 3 more times - why?

Tags: angular

It seems like this is probably my fault, but I can't work out why. Whenever I send an HTTP request anywhere in my app using `HttpClient` `post` or `get` and receive a non 2xx response, the request is immediately retried 3 more times (4 in total). I do not want this behaviour and am trying to turn if off.

This is the behaviour I would expect if I had piped `retry` into my observable pipeline, but I haven't. I do have some interceptors in place for auth and error handling, but I can't see anything in them that would be causing this behaviour. Can anyone suggest a way to track down what is causing these retries?

EDIT: Turns out this definitely is caused my by auth interceptor.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError, Observable, BehaviorSubject, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, take, switchMap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

/**
 * Disables this interceptor for a given HTTP request
 * Usage: this.http.get(`${environment.apiBase}someEndpoint`, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set(SkipAuthorizationHeader, '') })
 */
export const SkipAuthorizationHeader = 'X-Skip-Authorization-Handler';

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private refreshTokenInProgress = false;
  private readonly refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(private readonly auth: AuthService) { }

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // Abort if the request has instructed us via a custom header to do so
    if (req.headers.has(SkipAuthorizationHeader)) {
      // Delete the temporary header otherwise ASP.NET might get spooked by the unrecognised header
      const headers = req.headers.delete(SkipAuthorizationHeader);
      return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
    }

    if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      req = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      });
    }

    req = this.addAuthenticationToken(req);

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error && error.status === 401 && this.auth.canAttemptTokenRenewal) {
          // 401 errors are most likely going to be because we have an expired token that we need to refresh.
          if (this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
            // If refreshTokenInProgress is true, we will wait until refreshTokenSubject has a non-null value
            // which means the new token is ready and we can retry the request again
            return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
              filter(result => result !== null),
              take(1),
              switchMap(() => next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(req)))
            );
          } else {
            this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
            // Set the refreshTokenSubject to null so that subsequent API calls will wait until the new token has been retrieved
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
            return this.refreshAccessToken().pipe(
              switchMap((success: boolean) => {
                this.refreshTokenSubject.next(success);
                return next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(req));
              }),
              // When the call to refreshToken completes we reset the refreshTokenInProgress to false
              // for the next time the token needs to be refreshed
              finalize(() => this.refreshTokenInProgress = false)
            );
         }
        } else {
          throwError(error);
          return next.handle(req);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private refreshAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.auth.renewTokensAsync());
  }

  private addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {

    // If we do not have a token yet then we should not set the header.
    // Here we could first retrieve the token from where we store it.
    if (!this.auth.accessToken) {
      return request;
    }

    // If you are calling an outside domain then do not add the token.
    if (!request.url.match(environment.authDomainPattern)) {
      return request;
    }

    return request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`)
    });
  }
}
```

This code seems to cause all failed HTTP requests to retry three times. I always struggle with rxjs so it's obviously something bad I've done in here but I can't see what.

Comment: 1) No code = no aswer, 2) #1 is the most important.

Comment: So you know the cause now. Seams like problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
 return next.handle(req).pipe(
```

adn here

```
   } else {
      throwError(error);
      return next.handle(req);
    }
```

`else` block is called when you got error != 401. `req` is original request that has been made. So here you are doing the very same request on error.

I am not sure if it should be even reachable as I dont recall what `throwError` does (its been a while since I used angular)

Comment: It does hit that return next.handle(req) statement after throwError, and if I remove that statement it breaks things (You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable). My understanding is that next.handle passes the torch to the next interceptor and doesn't re-issue the the request necessarily - do I have that wrong?

Comment: You're completely right - I replaced both of the lines in that else block with "throw error" and now it works. Turns out my auth interceptor was only responsible for half the problem and another interceptor had the same issue, but that's what it was. next.handle re-issues the request, and throwError(error) is not the same as "throw error". Thanks a lot for your help!